# ASP.NET MVC Html.BeginForm decodes URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm requesting ASP.NET MVC the controller using the URL like this:

```
http://mysite.com/controller/myaction/Invalid%23name%25x
```

where `Invalid%23name%25x` is a parameter to

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string id) {
  return View();
}
```

The GET request works fine.

MyAction view looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
   ...
   <input name="Save" type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

The generated HTML is:

```
<form action="/Controller/MyAction/Invalid#name%x" method="post">
    ...
    <input name="Save" type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

When I click on "Save", the form gets posted and the POST request goes to

```
http://mysite.com/controller/myaction/Invalid#name%x
```

i.e. the initial URL is decoded. This means the the POST action receives only the first part of the parameter - "Invalid"

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(string id, ...) {
  return View();
}
```

How can I prevent `Html.BeginForm` from decoding the initial URLs in order to preserve the initial state?

Comment: What's the generated HTML?

Comment: <form action="/Controller/MyAction/Invalid#name%x" method="post">
    </form>

Comment: That looks like a bug in MVC.  Which version?

Comment: Yes, it looks like a bug, because Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "Controller") works fine, but Html.BeginForm() doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `ActionName` and `Controller` in your form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "Controller")) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally recommend you not to use `id` as string because as you have seen string can have many words in it.. let it mean what usually it does(numeric value).

use something like  `http://mysite.com/controller/myaction?Name=Invalid%23name%25x`

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string Name) {
    return View();
}
```

I suppose this would work for you..

Comment: My intention was to make the RESTful URLs like domain/controller/action/[human readable entity name] in order to make them looks informative for humans and avoid additional parameters.

Comment: @Omnituens I think then you should use _ or - in place of space.. as you can see in stack overflow Uri..